# why are my buttons not fitting properly?

Tags: android, android-layout

In landscape mode they properly stretch to fit the width..but in portrait the Exit button is extending too far to the right.

layout code: http://pastebin.com/KZVCdVJw

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` for your 'outer' `LinearLayout` instead of fixing it to `300dip`?

Comment: you could also use a relative layout(instead of linear) to specify how far you want your exit button to be from the right border

Comment: it fills properly with fill_parent, but for this dialog (theres more to it) I do want to constrain the width

Comment: @Sean, when i try using a RelativeLayout the buttons wont evenly spread with the weights.. any idea why? code: http://pastebin.com/Kx2Q8TUK

Comment: RelativeLayouts don't use the weight attribute.

Comment: you want your buttons to be in center or fill to width of the screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it wasnt properly fitting the screen was due to the orientation of the LinearLayout it was in. By changing the orientation from horizontal to vertical it solved the problem.